# Tensor product of irreducible representations of finite groups in GAP

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, representation-theory, tensor-products, gap

Is there a way with GAP to get the tensor product of representations in a certain basis?

To be more specific, I would like to cross-check with GAP the tensor products of, for example A5, as given in equations (82)-(86) in https://arxiv.org/abs/1003.3552

I give here eq.(82), so you don't need to open the paper itself to see an example of what I'm looking for.

\begin{eqnarray}
\left(
\begin{array}{c}
x_1  \\
x_2  \\   
x_3  \\
\end{array}
\right)_{{\bf 3}} 
\otimes 
\left(
\begin{array}{c}
y_1  \\
y_2  \\   
y_3  \\
\end{array}
\right)_{{\bf 3}}
&=&
(x_1y_1+x_2y_2+x_3y_3)_{{\bf 1}}
 \oplus
\left(
\begin{array}{c}
x_3y_2 - x_2y_3  \\
x_1y_3-x_3y_1   \\   
x_2y_1-x_1y_2 \\
\end{array}
\right)_{{\bf 3}}
\nonumber\\
& \oplus &
\left(
\begin{array}{c}
x_2y_2 - x_1y_1   \\
x_2y_1+x_1y_2   \\   
x_3y_2+x_2y_3  \\
x_1y_3+x_3y_1 \\
-\frac{1}{\sqrt3}(x_1y_1+x_2y_2-2x_3y_3)
\end{array}
\right)_{{\bf 5}},
\end{eqnarray}

For A5 I can do it fairly easy by hand, but for larger groups it would be nice to cross-check with GAP or something else.